# Unable to search/delete a continuously retrying sidekiq job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

One of my Sidekiq worker classes had validations for data size missing, hence one of the enqueued job is pulling in huge data from the database and failing abruptly with following message and immediately enqueuing another job with the same job_id.

> Error performing MyWorkerClass (Job ID:
> my_job_id) from Sidekiq(my_queue_name) in
> 962208.79ms: Sidekiq::Shutdown (Sidekiq::Shutdown):

As soon as I get this message, a new job is enqueued.

> Performing MyWorkerClass (Job ID: my_job_id) from
> Sidekiq(my_queue_name) with arguments: 1, {"param1"=>"param1_value",
> "param2"=>"param2_value", "param3"=>"param3_value"}

I am figuring out a way to fix this problem but for now I want to stop this particular job from running continuously. I couldn't find this job on my sidekiq UI dashboard.
Also I tried to find and delete this job using following methods but couldn't find the job. All the variables printed below are `Nil`.

```
a = Sidekiq::Queue.new('my_queue_name').find_job("my_job_id")
b = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find_job("my_job_id")
c = Sidekiq::RetrySet.new.find_job("my_job_id")
d = Sidekiq::JobSet.new('my_queue_name').find_job("my_job_id")
puts a.inspect
puts b.inspect
puts c.inspect
puts d.inspect
```

I want help with the following:

1. How to avoid this abrupt shutdown for long running jobs in the future
2. Find the long running job and kill it.

Thank you in Advance !

Comment: You could set the worker options to prevent retrying the job if it fails, by setting retry: false, or retry: 0 if you want the job to go to the dead set.